Batch script to unarchive multiple archives using 7zip
I'm trying to unarchive a lot of archives in a folder. I'm trying to archive them just outside, without making a folder per archive.
I'm using this code
@echo off
setlocal

rem Set the path to the 7-Zip executable
set "7z_path=C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

rem Set the path to the folder containing the archives
set "source_folder=C:\Users\blabla"

rem Echo the paths for debugging
echo 7z_path is set to: "%7z_path%"
echo source_folder is set to: "%source_folder%"

rem Change to the source folder
cd /d "%source_folder%"

rem Extract each archive file in the folder
for %%i in (*.zip *.rar *.7z) do (
    "%7z_path%" x "%%i" -aoa -o"%source_folder%"
)

endlocal
pause

But it doesn't work with the following error
'"z_pathsource_folder"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
When debugging I notice the
7z_path is set to: "z_path" which is not correct obviously, but I don't understand what I did wrong. This problem might be causing the error above.
Any help is appreciated, ty.

As an alternative to not using 7zip, in Windows this can be run from the command line for /r %v in (*.zip) do tar -xf "%v". It won't show progress as 7zip but it might be faster.

Arguments to batch scripts are called with the syntax %1, %2, %3, etc. These variables are expanded to their values before all other variables in the script are. Because you're calling your variable %7z_path%, that's being interpreted as %7 followed by the string z_path%.
Change your variable name to something that does not start with a number, like %sevenzip_path%.
